# Not getting full path in breadcrumb form Category page to Product description page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, breadcrumbs

I have a parent category SHOP and in shop, there are products. When I click on products, it goes on product description page. However, breadcrumb shows  "home- > product1"  instead of  "home -> shop -> product1"

Comment: Do you have category paths enabled for product URLs in your admin: Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs? Try setting it to "Yes" if you don't.

Comment: yes its already yes :(  @Lez  it work fine foe few minutes then start home -> product1   . link of website is http://52.11.243.166/

Comment: On local machine its aswell working good @Lez

Comment: I checked your site, and tried 5+ product pages. All show breadcrumbs fine: as home -> shop -> category -> product. Maybe it's just some specific product?

Comment: @Lez  I dont know why Option  again went as NO , it happened 3 times. Now I have set and  its working fine :D thanks for help. It was misleading me dont know why. as after selecting I didt verify either it is yes or no.

Comment: This will happen if the product has been visited from search. If FPC is enabled that will then the breadcrumbs on the product page will stick even if later visited from the category pages.

Comment: @harri  what is FPC ? I didnt get bro. Maybe that is reason of weird behavior. but didnt get what you said why its happening.

Comment: The full page cache. I did have a look at your site quickly however and it didnt seem to be the case but couldnt tell if the cache  was enabled

Comment: If it does turn out to be the case then give me a shout i do have a solution for fixing that. its not perfect but it makes sure there is always proper breadcrumbs in place search or not.

Comment: yes can you kindly share that please ? @harri

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Possible Issue

This issue can occur when the **full page cache** caches a product page when visited from search or directly via the url.

As the breadcrumbs when visited from search do not show the full category path, the page will then be saved in the **FPC** with the breadcrumbs as **Home > Product**, even when later visited from a category.

### Possible Solution

To overcome this I created a module which takes the deepest category path and uses that for **breadcrumbs** mainly so that users can see the path when searching for products.

In my case there was never breadcrumbs on products as page cache was warmed up from a sitemap and so similar to searching for products, directly viewing a product from URL showed no breadcrumbs.

This module below however replaces the default breadcrumbs behavior and should show breadcrumbs regardless once installed.

> https://github.com/harrigo/EverCrumbs

### Issues

This will cause some incorrect paths if product in **multiple categories** and so will show wrong path for shallower path. This would of been the case in default Magento however depending which page was visited first.

### Improvements

This could be improved to overcome the issue of incorrect paths when visited from another shallower category path however never got around to it as products were not listed in multiple categories in my case.

Ideally this needs to be modified to have breadcrumbs hole punched so they are always correct on category pages and then just replace search breadcrumbs with these new breadcrumbs for search.

Comment: great help. I have one more question, can we change path when we click on "related product " it took us to  home ->productname  . can it be changed ?

Comment: This should change that product also. Test it see how it goes and let me know if you have issues and ill see if i can help further.

Comment: I pasted this folder in app/code/harrigo   and now this error showing  Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Harrigo\EverCrumbs\Block\Breadcrumbs does not exist

Comment: Should be in app/code/harrigo/EverCrumbs

Comment: now path is   app/code/harrigo/EverCrumbs/EverCrumbs-master    and this happend  Setup version for module 'Harrigo_EverCrumbs' is not specified

Comment: Ah sorry no just keep as was and  EverCrumbs-master  to EverCrumbs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71341/discussion-between-harri-and-ephemeral).

Comment: kindly check on live site of mine its working perfect bro :D

Comment: Its fix of this open issue o github aswell   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7967   :) .